# Set android alarms in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm pretty new to react native and I would like to programatically set the android (I don't need this for ios) native alarms (those who can ring even if the phone is off). I already searched but I only found push notifications working like alarms (it can ring, but not if the phone is off). Is it possible, and if yes, how ? If it is possible, not in java, I don't know this language.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this 
[library](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events)

There is a good possibility of alarm with [example](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events/wiki/Event-alarms)

Comment: It isn't for Google Calendar ?

Comment: There is an alarm option there
  By time

Comment: And is it possible to set a music or a ringtone for those alarms ?

Comment: i dont see this option in documentation ,
can you voit for me?